# Azure SQL database deploy SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, azure-sql-database

When I try to deploy my database (SQL Server 2012) this error occurs:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Please help me

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to get used to "network-related or instance-specific" errors when connecting to Azure SQL databases.  Connections fail often, and you *will* need some kind of retry logic.

But in this case it looks like you may need to whitelist your IP.  In the Azure portal, find the place where you make firewall exclusions and add your client IP.  If you're trying to connect from your own machine, then the portal will have a one-click way to add that one.

And of course, double-check your connection string.